# How to send selected category on another page using php without showing in url

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, categories

Hello i am very new to web development. 
I have two page :
1. show_category.php (All category is showing here)
2. listing.php (All product of this category is showing in table)
First page is showing category from database.

show_category.php:

```
 <div class="row">
         <?php 
            include 'connection.php';

            $query="SELECT * FROM subcat WHERE pid='1' ";
            $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
            while ($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
          ?>
        <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
          <div class="card border-left-primary shadow h-100 py-2">
            <a href="javascript:$('#myform_id').submit();">
              <form id="myform_id" method="post" role="form" action="listing.php">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
                    <div class="col mr-2">
                      <!-- <div class="text-xs font-weight-bold text-primary text-uppercase mb-1">Earnings (Monthly)</div> -->
                      <div class="h5 mb-0 font-weight-bold text-gray-800">
                        <p><?php echo $rows['name'];?>
                            <?php echo $rows['id']; ?> 
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
         <?php
            }
          ?>    
      </div>
```

i have tried something

```
<a href="javascript:$('#myform_id').submit();">
              <form id="myform_id" method="post" role="form" action="listing.php">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
                    <div class="col mr-2">
                      <div class="h5 mb-0 font-weight-bold text-gray-800">
                        <p><?php echo $rows['name'];?>
                            <?php echo $rows['id']; ?> 
                            <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $rows['name'];?>">
                            <input type="hidden" name="pid" value="<?php echo $rows['id'];?>">
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </a>
```

But this is always sending only first category on listing.php? How can i get selected category's name and id on listing.php

listing.php:

```
$id=$_POST['id'];$name=$_POST['name'];echo $name;echo $id;
```

Comment: I don't see `input` fields in the first code. I guess inserting the `hidden input` in the first code you showed should do it. (instead of just echoing rows). (put the content of  `<div class="h5 mb-0 font-weight-bold text-gray-800">` from 2nd example at the same place in the 1st example.

Comment: You should go and learn some HTML basics. You can not nest a `form` that includes “interactive” elements into `a`, that is massively invalid HTML to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

You want a $_POST variable instead of a $_GET variable.

So inside your while loop instead of having a link like:

```
href=products.php?cat_id=$id
```

Which you can then access on your products page with $_GET.

You should have a form element with input hidden with the value of the `$id` and the form itself should have `method='POST'` and `action='products.php'`.

This will then redirect to the products page without the added bit in the URL and you can access it using $_POST

In this case you will need to have an individual form element for each item in your loop.

### Edit

```
$query="SELECT * FROM subcat WHERE pid='1'";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
while ($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<form method="POST" action="listings.php">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$row['id'].'" name="id">;
    echo '<input type="submit" value="Go to this ID">';
    echo '</form>';
}
```

New form for each id inside the while loop or you will only get the first one.

Then on your listings.php page just use `$_POST['id']` to access it.

Comment: The reason you're only getting the first id is because it is outside of the loop, you need a different form for each element for this to work. Another option would be to use JS https://www.javascripture.com/FormData

Comment: hey Paddy this is working fine with only first category. When i am selecting another category it always sending first category on listing.php page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to take a slightly different approach to this - you are creating a new form for each category which is unnecessary. I would do it this way

1. **show_categories.php:** Loop through your subcat rows to create links with GET variables
2. **listings.php:** take the GET variables and find the associated listings

categories.php

```
include 'connection.php';
$query="SELECT * FROM subcat WHERE pid='1' ";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result);

foreach($row as $category) {
    echo "<p><a href=listing.php?id='".$category['id']."'>".$category['name']."</a></p>";
}
```

listing.php

```
if(isset($_GET['id']} {
     //get your listings from the database with the category id and display them
}
```

This assumes that your listings table has a subcat column with the id of the category it is linked to.

**Alternative with POST.**

categories.php

```
include 'connection.php';
$query="SELECT * FROM subcat WHERE pid='1' ";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result);

foreach($row as $category) {
    echo "<div><form method='POST' action='listing.php'>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$category['id']."'>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='name' value='".$category['name']."'>";
    echo "<p onclick='this.closest('form').submit();return false;'>".$category['name']."</p>";
    echo "</form></div>";
}
```

listing.php

```
if(isset($_POST['id']} {
 //get your listings from the database with the category id and display them
}
```

Comment: thank you fraggley  this is working fine for me. But id is showing in url can i achieve this with post method.

Comment: Sure, I'll edit my answer to include this. Although is there a reason for hiding the id?

Comment: Thanks Fraggley. NO, there is no reason for hiding the id.

Comment: Both GET and POST solutions are in the answer above